# How to Select the Max Value after a Count in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a query:

```
SELECT
  CST_CON_ID as ID_USER,
  X_TYPE_FOURTH_LVL as ELEMENT_TYPE,
  COUNT(X_TYPE_FOURTH_LVL) as T_REPEAT
FROM
  SIEBEL.S_SRV_REQ
GROUP BY
   CST_CON_ID,
   X_TYPE_FOURTH_LVL
ORDER BY
   CST_CON_ID;
```

Which returns the following information when run:

```
ID_USER      ELEMENT_TYPE    T_REPEAT
1-1HQR-1380   REPOSITION      3
1-1HQR-1380   CANCELED        4
1-1HQR-1380   INFORMATION     1
1-1HQR-1380   SELLS           90
1-1HQR-1380   PROMOTIONS      3
1-1HQR-1380   ACCOUNTS        5
1-1HQR-1250   ACTIONS         34
1-1HQR-1250   PROG            60
1-1HQR-1250   INFORMATION     3
1-1HQR-1560   SELLS           40
1-1HQR-1560   BUYS            2
1-1HQR-1560   REPOSITION      1
1-1HQR-1560   PROMOTIONS      70
```

But now I want only to extract for each `ID_USER` the max value of `T_REPEAT`.
The expected output I want would look like this:

```
ID_USER      ELEMENT_TYPE    T_REPEAT
1-1HQR-1380   SELLS           90
1-1HQR-1250   PROG            60
1-1HQR-1560   PROMOTIONS      70
```

Is it possible to get this output using only a single query?

Comment: It is: what you wrote already becomes a subquery, and in an outer query you apply the additional logic. Question though: what is the required output if for a user, the maximum T_REPEAT is reached more than once? What if your first user had 90 SELLS and also 90 INFORMATION?

Comment: in that case it extract both  for example  1-1HQR-1380   SELLS    90 and 1-1HQR-1380   INFORMATION    90

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use of `row_number()` :

```
SELECT ID_USER, ELEMENT_TYPE, T_REPEAT
FROM (SELECT CST_CON_ID as ID_USER, X_TYPE_FOURTH_LVL as ELEMENT_TYPE,
             COUNT(X_TYPE_FOURTH_LVL) as T_REPEAT,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CST_CON_ID ORDER BY COUNT(X_TYPE_FOURTH_LVL) DESC) AS Seq
      FROM SIEBEL.S_SRV_REQ
      GROUP BY CST_CON_ID, X_TYPE_FOURTH_LVL
     ) t
WHERE Seq = 1;
```

EDIT : If you have a ties with count then use `dense_rank()` function instead :

Comment: "One option is to use" isn't all that helpful. It would be better to explain in what cases ROW_NUMBER() will work, and when it won't. (Specifically dealing with ties for the max count for a user.)

Comment: @GoranKutlaca - No, it isn't. I asked in a comment what should happen in the case of ties. The OP answered: in that case ALL tied rows should appear in the output. The `ROW_NUMBER()` solution only returns one row per user, even in the case of ties. The solution proposed here can be modified easily to accommodate, but the solution AS POSTED is not "a correct answer to the question" (essentially, because "the question" was ambiguous without the clarification on ties).

Comment: @mathguy yes i have problem when i have the same value (T_REPEAT) in the same ID_USER with the solution that propose Yogesh Sharma is almost that i want but i have the problem that you say, do you have an idea of how to modified the query?

Comment: @Y2KSAVE. . . Have you checked with my EDIT Comment ?

Comment: @YogeshSharma oh i didnt see your edit sorry now is complete sorry and thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the current statement in a subquery.

```
SELECT ID_USER, ELEMENT_TYPE, MAX(T_REPEAT) 
FROM (
   SELECT
     CST_CON_ID as ID_USER,
     X_TYPE_FOURTH_LVL as ELEMENT_TYPE,
     COUNT(X_TYPE_FOURTH_LVL) as T_REPEAT
   FROM
     SIEBEL.S_SRV_REQ
   GROUP BY
      CST_CON_ID,
      X_TYPE_FOURTH_LVL
   ORDER BY
      T_REPEAT
   )
GROUP BY ID_USER
```

Comment: In this code it is not defined that `MAX(T_REPEAT)` is grouped by `ID_USER` only.

Comment: You are missing the `GROUP BY` clause. After you add it, you will see that you can't select `ELEMENT_TYPE` in the outer query. The problem is more subtle than your attempted solution.

Comment: Right... Added ORDER BY in stead of GROUP BY. My excuses.